# Объединить функции resize и scroll в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть две функции. В первой при размере окна больше 725px к классу header добавляется класс sticky, на меньших разрешениях удаляется.

```
function checkWidth() {
    if ($(window).width() > 725) {
        $('header').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass('sticky');
    }
}
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Во второй функции при скролле более 10px к header прибавляется класс sticky.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var height = $(window).scrollTop();
if(height > 10){
$('header').addClass('sticky');
$('.header-wrapper').addClass('topbar-size');
} else{
$('header').removeClass('sticky');
$('.header-wrapper').removeClass('topbar-size');
}
});
```

проблема в том, что на разрешениях меньше 725px sticky не должен прибавляться к header и должен отключаться скролл. я не знаю как сделать правильно.
я нашарил что правильно объединять функции надо по такому принципу:

```
var func = function(e){ /* resize and scroll logic */};
$(window).scroll(func).resize(func);
```

но я не понимаю как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вам использовать JS там, где можно сделать на CSS. Для задачи `sticky` достаточно написать:

```
header {
  /* стили, когда ширина viewport > 725 */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 725px) {
  header {
    /* стили, когда ширина viewport <= 725 */
  }
}
```

Для задачи со скроллом добавить:

```
var $window = $(window), $body = $(document.body);

$window.on('resize scroll update', function() {
  $body.attr('data-scrolled', $window.scrollTop() > 10 ? 'Y' : 'N');
}).trigger('update');
```

И затем написать стили с учетом скролла:

```
body[data-scrolled="N"] header {
  /* стили без скролла и когда ширина viewport > 725 */
}

body[data-scrolled="Y"] header {
  /* стили со скроллом и когда ширина viewport > 725 */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 725px) {

  body[data-scrolled="N"] header {
    /* стили без скролла и когда ширина viewport <= 725 */
  }

  body[data-scrolled="Y"] header {
    /* стили со скроллом и когда ширина viewport <= 725 */
  }

}
```

Да, здесь возможно придется дублировать одинаковые стили, но такой вариант гораздо более оптимизирован с точки зрения отрисовки браузером изменяющегося контента.

Answer (score 1):

Не пугайтесь большому количеству кода, для казалось бы, такого простого действия.

Суть в чём, тут много проверок, связанных с оптимизацией - в чём суть этой оптимизации:
Без неё, наша проверка будет срабатывать **каждый раз** когда будет выполнен `scroll` или `resize`, с данной проверкой, будет выполнятся только тогда, когда все условия будут совпадать.

Вот реализация данного решения на jQuery

```js
let header = $('header'),
  h_min = 725, // Минимальная ширина экрана для работы скрипта
  s_pos = 10,  // Позиция скролла, при которой включается `sticky`
  isSticky = $(window).scrollTop() > s_pos ? true : false, // Некая оптимизация, с изначальной проверкой
  isMinSize = $(window).width() < h_min ? false : true;    // Некая оптимизация, с изначальной проверкой

if(isSticky === true && isMinSize === true) header.addClass('sticky'); // При изначальной проверке мы проверяем, что если позиция скролла изначально больше минимальной высоты для работы скрипта, при этом минимальная ширина не достигнута, то выдаём класс `sticky`

$(window).on({ // Вещаем обработчики на скролл и ресайз
  'scroll': function() {
    if(isMinSize === true) { // Если минимальная ширина достигнута, то `sticky` добавляться или удаляться не будет.. Если проверка прошла, то:
      if($(window).scrollTop() >= s_pos && isSticky === false) { // Если позиция скролла больше или равна минимальной высоте, то
        isSticky = true; // Меняем "флаг" для оптимизации
        header.addClass('sticky'); // вешаем класс `sticky`
      } else
      if($(window).scrollTop() < s_pos && isSticky === true) { // Тут такое же принцип действия как и выше, но наоборот
        isSticky = false;
        header.removeClass('sticky');
      }
    }
  },
  'resize': function() { // Далее проверяем ресайз
    if($(window).width() < h_min && isMinSize === true) { // Если ширина окна меньше минимальной ширины, то:
      isMinSize = false; // Выставляем "флаг" для оптимизации
      if($(window).scrollTop() >= s_pos) { // Тут такое же принцип действия как и выше, но наоборот
        isSticky = false;
        header.removeClass('sticky');
      }
    } else 
    if($(window).width() >= h_min && isMinSize === false) { // Тут аналогично проверке выше, только так же наоборот
      isMinSize = true;
      if($(window).scrollTop() >= s_pos) { // Если позиция скролла больше или равна минимальной высоте, то
        isSticky = true; // Меняем "флаг" для оптимизации
        header.addClass('sticky'); // вешаем класс `sticky`
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 150vh;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
}

header.sticky {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header></header>
```

Когда нажмёте "Выполнить код" ничего работать не будет - потому что сниппет по ширине меньше `725px`, если нажмёте в правой стороне `На всю страницу`, то код будет работать.
При этом дописал некую механику.
Если скролл больше `s_pos`, и ширина экрана становится больше `h_min` - то класс `sticky` удалится. Так же работает и в обратную сторону.